# Subclassing NSCalendar?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make a subclass of NSCalendar, but without much luck. I've tried two ways:

1. thorough categories. I can create a modified object and a test method that I added (not part of NSCalendar) works just fine, but overriden methods don't work - e.g. if I call dateFromComponents:, the NSCalendar method is apparently called, not what I wrote in the category definition
2. regular subclass. In this case I can't even create an instance: initWithCalendarIdentifier throws a _CFRequireConcreteImplementation exception. Initially I only had a couple of methods overriden in the subclass, but then I've overriden all of the (documented) NSCalendar methods - and the result is the same.

Is it even possible to subclass NSCalendar?

The reason I want to do it is to make repeating Local Notifications with non-standard repeat intervals. The default functionality allows Local Notifications to repeat every [calendar unit], but I need irregular intervals - e.g. I can emulate "every 15 minutes" notifications by creating 4 "every hour" notifications 15 minutes apart, but I need them to fire at, say T+20, T+22, T+24, T+44, T+46, T+66 minutes and so on (T is the start time) - the interval between notifications is 20 minutes, then 2 minutes, then 20 minutes again and so on.

I was hoping that, since UILocalNotification wants an NSCalendar (in repeatCalendar property) to calculate when to fire the next notification, I can achieve what I want by overriding, say, dateFromComponents to just return [NSDate dateWithIntervalSinceNow] with interval alternating between 20 and 2 minutes - but my cunning plan seems to have a major problem because of the inability to subclass NSCalendar.

Edit: This whole thing is needed for when the app is in the background. In the foreground I use timers, just like No one in particular suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you do manage to subclass NSCalendar, I doubt it'll work. I strongly suspect that local notifications are scheduled by SpringBoard, and I don't think it's going to launch/resume your app every time it needs to see what the next fire date is.

The first step is to find out *what* UILocalNotification is doing with your calendar. The easiest way to do this is to write an NSObject subclass which forwards undefined method calls and prints log messages (respondsToSelector:, methodSignatureForSelector:, forwardInvocation:). Generally, you want something like `if ([super respondsToSelector:selector]) { return [super ...]; } else { return [target ...]; }`.

Then, the easiest hack is to write a class which implements the necessary methods of NSCalendar for your purposes.

You might also consider calling `[super init]`; `-[NSCalendar initWithCalendarIdentifier:]` is likely to return a different `self` (e.g. `[self release]; return [[NSGregorianCalendar alloc] init]`), and you don't want that. What calendar identifier are you passing it? Maybe it's complaining that it requires a "concrete implementation" that it knows about for the calendar identifier you're passing.

Comment: Creating an NSobject subclass looks like a good idea, thanks! And it looks it _is_ being used somehow, because when I actually fed it that NSObject derivative instead of the NSCalendar, there was a rather weird simulator crash :)
I used to pass it a regular Gregorian calendar, nothing fancy (and I don't care what calendar to use anyway)

Answer (score 1):

A direct inherit from NSCalendar is tricky because I think that it's a class cluster. I'm a bit fuzzy on this concept so I'll give you a link to the Apple document instead of making a greater fool of myself.

http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34

Answer (score 0):

Try using the NSTimer method

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:
```

Set the repeats to TRUE and have a time interval of 2 minutes. Have a counter that you set to 1 or 10. Everytime the selector is called you decrement the counter until it reaches 0 when you do your work and reset the counter.

Comment: NSTimer is cool but doesn't work in background (and I need it for the background) - sorry, I looks like I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Timers don't run when your app is suspended in the background, which is the entire point of repeating local notifications.